# How to specified partial members of __all__ in automodule using sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there a way to output partial members (too much classes) instead of all members from **all** in package.module, i don't want to specified these manully because of too much members and inconvenient maintenance.

```
.. automodule:: package.module
     :members:
```

I thought of two ways.

1. Variable replacement. Define a list (just named temp_all) that contained all the specified members in conf.py , replace it in automodule as showed below:

   ```
   .. automodule:: package.module
        :members: temp_all
   ```

   I tried to use rst_prolog defined in config.py, but it  doesn't seem to work for automodule.

   ```
   temp_all = ', '.join(package.module.temp_all)

   rst_epilog = '.. |temp_all| replace:: %s' % temp_all
   ```
2. specified partial members directly with package.module.temp_all in automodule:

   ```
   .. automodule:: package.module
        :members: package.module.temp_all
   ```

I don't know the way to do it.Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you define a list that contains all the "partial" members, then you do specify them manually. I don't see how you can get around that.

Comment: The value of the `:members:` option must be a literal list of members. It cannot be a variable. Please explain what you mean by "partial members".